# How to hit load balancer with multiple host ip through selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, spoofing, amazon-elb

I have a situation, my current application is configured with load balancer and based on the different machine (VM) host ip, the URL will redirect to different node of the application.

Now if i hit the application url from VM1, it will redirect to node1, and if the same url hitted from VM2, it will redirect to node2. Here node means same application but connected with different DB. So how i can performtransaction from node1 and check the same reflected in node2 (its feature of application) through selenium automation?

Can anyone let me know how we can configure proxy with webdriver (through capabilities or any other way) so that from same machine i can access both node1 and node2 application parameterizing the Different host ip? Let say the both ip are fixed as of now and we dont need to get it dynamically.

I googled about ip spoofing but that doesnt help me, may be i did something wrong.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly it sounds like you need a way to specify which node for your loadbalancer to select to run the test? You should be able to specify the exact ip you want to use (to bypass the loadbalancer). If this doesn't work, you may need to configure your loadbalancer to read a header that you can then specify the node.

Comment: Yes you absolutely understood it correctly. I need a way to specify host ip to the webdriver so that once the URL hitted from VM2, it redirect to node1 instead node2. And you said i should be able to specify the same (to bypass loadbalancer) ???? Can you please let me know how to do that? Is there any easy way? I would like to give a try and comeback if it serve my purpose. The second option is the easiest option but i dont want the build team to get involved into this. Help me out if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can install or configure selenium grid on the both VM's (ex. VM1 and VM2). 
1. launch your browser on VM1 grid and do your transaction. 
2. Then launch another browser on VM2 Grid and check/validate the transaction happened or not.

Comment: I appreciate your response but it will not serve my purpose. Its not like a parallel run, test cases needs to be performed on both the node partially. Its kind of end to end flow, perform some transaction on node1, save some unique ref generated, go back to node2 and use those ref number saved from node1 and perform validation/ transaction on node2, again something needed to be saved to complete the full flow. In this grid concept i will not be able to pass reference number from 1 vm to other vm. hence i am trying to achieve to access both from same machine (not sure even if it is possible)

Comment: You can pass reference to another instance if your launches the two browsers in same script. It should b linear. You should launch the first browser on grid 1 and do your transaction and note down or save the transaction details in a variable. launch the second browser on grid 2 and search the transaction details from VM2. Grid is not only for parallel execution. it can be other purpose as well.